# Why do the default and empty constructor generate different machine code in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, code-generation

When looking at the [x86-64asm generated by GCC 7.1](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'class+a+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++int+aint%3B%0A%0A++a()+%7B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+b+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++int+bint%3B%0A%0A++b()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++a+ac%3B%0A++ac.aint+%3D+2%3B%0A%0A++b+bc%3B%0A++bc.bint+%3D+5%3B%0A%0A++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) for the following code I found that the constructors for `a` generates code while `b` doesn't have a label for a constructor.

```
class a {
public:
  int aint;

  a() { }
};

class b {
public:
  int bint;

  b() = default;
};

int main() {
  a ac;
    //         lea     rax, [rbp-4]
    //         mov     rdi, rax
    //         call    a::a()
  ac.aint = 2;
    //         mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2


  b bc;             // no instructions for this statement
  bc.bint = 5;
    //         mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5

  return 0;
}
```

Why would the code generated here for the constructors be so different?  Why wouldn't `a() { }` generate the same code as `b() = default`?

Comment: Different code such as?

Comment: @EJP, he showed the code in godbolt in the link.

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimisation?   If without (e.g. `-O0`) that would be the reason.

Comment: @prl He should have showed it *here.*  Links are not acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no optimization (-O0), gcc generates code that can be easily debugged, so it includes every statement and function call in the source. You can set a breakpoint on a::a. With any higher optimization level, you won't see that constructor call.